# How to prevent a local resource assigments on a task by event handler?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I want to prevent local resources from being assigned to tasks.
Only corporate resources must be assigned.
How to implement this at the time of assignments by event handler?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Application Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/project/concepts/using-events-with-application-and-project-objects). Because assignments can be modified directly in a task table and in the Task Information dialog box, two event handlers are required. Create a class module called Events with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_ProjectBeforeAssignmentChange(ByVal asg As Assignment, ByVal Field As PjAssignmentField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Field = pjAssignmentResourceName Then
        If Not ThisProject.Resources(NewVal).Enterprise Then
            MsgBox "Resource '" & NewVal & "' cannot be added.", vbOKOnly, "Only enterprise resources are allowed"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub App_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(ByVal tsk As Task, ByVal Field As PjField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Field = pjTaskResourceNames Then
        Dim resNames() As String
        resNames = Split(NewVal, ",")
        Dim AllEnterprise As Boolean
        AllEnterprise = True
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To UBound(resNames)
            AllEnterprise = AllEnterprise And ThisProject.Resources(resNames(i)).Enterprise
        Next i
        If Not AllEnterprise Then
            MsgBox "Resource Names '" & NewVal & "' is invalid.", vbOKOnly, "Only enterprise resources are allowed"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the ThisProject module, add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim eClass As New Events

Private Sub Project_Open(ByVal pj As Project)
    InitializeEventHandler
End Sub

Sub InitializeEventHandler()
    Set eClass.App = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, it's work! thank you! But one quastion: if assignments modified directly in  in the Task Information dialog box - it work both event handlers. Is it possible to make only one work and the second canceled?

Comment: Oh, if use only one event handler (on assignments modified directly) - it work when assignments modified in the Task Information dialog box too.

Comment: And where is the fird way to modify assignments in Project.

Comment: And where is the fird way to modify assignments in Project. In Project menu: Resource -> Resources assignments. May be my task solved in another way: By event handler wich prevent to creating of local resource in resources list? It will save us from the several event handlers.