# MS Project - Disable resource

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto, ms-project

I am creating a Microsoft Project add-in. Depending on the value of a resource's custom text column (let's say Text30), can I disable a resource from showing up when trying to assign it to a task?

So for example, if a row has a Text30 value of `Inactive`, it shouldn't be available to the Project file user to assign it to a task, but it should still be in the Resource Sheet. Below, row 1 would be available as a resource, and row 2 wouldn't show up when assigning resources to a task.

[image]

Comment: The short answer is no--resources cannot be disabled on a task-by-task basis. However, there is a solution shown in this question: [How to prevent a local resource assigments on a task by event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990825/how-to-prevent-a-local-resource-assigments-on-a-task-by-event-handler). The VBA code is easily ported to vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Rachel's linked question I managed to find a workaround. I added a Text column called Active Status (`Text30` in my case). Then, using `Application.ProjectBeforeTaskChange` I checked if the new value is a resource that has the column `Text30` of value `Active`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/project.application.projectbeforetaskchange) is the link to the MS Project event. Below is the code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject

Private Sub Application_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(tsk As Task, Field As PjField, NewVal As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ProjectBeforeTaskChange

    CheckResourceValidity(NewVal, Cancel)

End Sub


Private Sub CheckResourceValidity(NewVal As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim res As Resource
    Dim newValList = NewVal.Split(",")

    If Not IsStartup(newValList) Then

        For Each splitNewVal In newValList
            ' currentProject is the currently active Project
            res = currentProject.Resources.Item(splitNewVal)

            If splitNewVal = res.Name Then

                If res.Text30 <> "Active" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You are trying to assign an inactive resource to a task. Please choose an active resource.",
                                    "Assigning inactive resource", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                    Cancel = True
                End If

            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub


' The event ProjectBeforeTaskChange is called when a .mpp file with data inside is opened
Private Function IsStartup(newValList As Object) As Boolean

    Dim res As Resource

    For Each x In newValList

        Try
            res = GlobalVariables.currentProject.ProjResources.Item(x)
        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
            Return True
        End Try

    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

The program will not allow the user to add a resource to a task if the resource doesn't have a Text30 value of 'Active'.

**ATTENTION:**
This event will trigger only if you assign the resource through the Gantt Chart. If you assign through the *Resource tab -> Assign Resource*, the event won't be triggered. The event `ProjectBeforeAssignmentNew` will be triggered through the *Assign Resource* and through the Gantt Chart. The only downside is that I didn't find a way to access the value being changed through the `ProjectBeforeAssignmentNew` event. You can find the event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/project.application.projectbeforeassignmentnew).